# How do I convert a .stl to .js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I want to make a 3-D viewer using WebGL and the imported model I need to access is an STL or .stl file. I believe I need to convert an STL file to .js so that it can be compatible in a web browser. How do I make the conversion while keeping the integrity and detail of the STL file?

Comment: STL is a data format, JavaScript a programming language, so I'm not sure what this "conversion" would have to look like exactly? Googling `javascript stl webgl` seems to yield some promising results though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not really have to create a `.js` file. You can use the `three.js loader` for `.stl` files which is located in [`examples\js\loaders\STLLoader.js`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/STLLoader.js) (from your main download location of three.js).

In addition you can look at [`examples\webgl_loader_stl.html`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_stl.html) to see how this is done.

Comment: So, this is the code I need to load my STL file: * var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
 *  loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
 *
 *   var geometry = event.content;
 *   scene.add( new THREE.Mesh( geometry ) );
 *
 *  } );
 *  loader.load( './models/stl/slotted_disk.stl' );

Comment: Yes this is the code. You will need some material also (which you can find in the example) because the stl file does not define material. Please accept the answer if correct.